# Access jenkins build job paramter via shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

My Jenkins build job is triggered via an external service by parameters that I can see in the left menu under parameters. So I want to react on that parameters via my shell script in the Jenkins job itself.

I could only find information about parameterized build but not about using that parameters I talked about.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 2):

As stated here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build you can reference your parameter BAR as $BAR.